# Delete Email on Server using javax.mail

Tags: java, email, imap

I am receiving emails from the server using the IMAP protocol like:

```
Store store = session.getStore(mEmailProtocol);
store.connect(mEmailServer, mEmailUser, mEmailPassword);

Folder folder = store.getDefaultFolder();
if (folder == null) {
    throw new MessagingException("No default folder"); //$NON-NLS-1$
}
Folder inboxfolder = folder.getFolder("INBOX"); //$NON-NLS-1$
if (inboxfolder == null) {
    throw new MessagingException("No INBOX"); //$NON-NLS-1$
}

Message[] msgs = inboxfolder.getMessages();
```

This is working very fine and I can store the emails and attachments on the disk.

***Question***:
Do I have the possibility to delete files from the Server, so that they are no longer available, when a client tries to receive all emails? If so, please tell me how.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You should be able to do this via the standard APIs.

First you need to get a reference to the `Message` (or messages) you want to delete - if you're successfully reading them then you're already able to do this.  Now, there's no explicit delete() operation, but you can mark a message as deleted like so:

```
message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
```

This will mark the message as deleted (which is typically what a delete operation will do in a desktop IMAP client).  In order to force the deleted messages to be expunged, when you're finished with the `Folder`(s) in which they reside, call

```
folder.close(true);
```

where the true flag instructs the server to expunge all deleted messages.

And voila!  The client should no longer see these messages when he connects to the server with any IMAP client.

EDIT:

Don't forget to open the folder in READ_WRITE mode otherwise the messages will not actually be deleted from the server.

```
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
```

See: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JavaMail/contents.html#JavaMailDeleting

Comment: Then give it the answer used flag.

Comment: method name should be [setFlag] not [setFlags] [message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);]

Comment: @MohammedSayed Thanks, you're right.  I thought this might be down to an API change in a recent version, but no - it's just been wrong for nearly four years!