# Deleting mail permanently using java Mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have been using java mail to automate Gmail operations.
One of the operation is to delete mail and I use following for it -

```
message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
```

but doing so only pushes my mails to spam folder.

I am wondering if there is a straight way to delete mail permanently instead of deleting mail from "inbox" first and then searching mails in "spam " folder and deleting them.

Comment: May be a different question but I can not use Folder spam = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Spam"); to get mails from spam folder.... What could be folder name for "spam" folder

Comment: I hope the following post has the answer [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464706/delete-email-on-server-using-javax-m][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464706/delete-email-on-server-using-javax-mail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=78755:

> If you want to delete a message from all folders, move it to the [Gmail]/Trash folder.
>
> If you delete a message from [Gmail]/Spam or [Gmail]/Trash, it will be deleted permanently.

However, that page doesn't give any indication that your approach would move mail to the spam folder; and it implies that you *should* see a folder named `[Gmail]/Spam`; so maybe it doesn't apply to your situation, somehow? I think you'll just have to try its approach, and see whether it works for you!

Answer (score 3):

You told that you are trying

```
 message.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
```

did you tried 
`folder.close(true);`
this will expunge all messages with DELETED flags.

Comment: It does not for Gmail; the message will still be in the archive (All Mail) then.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the flag to Flags.Flag.DELETED only marks the email as deleted.

You need to call

folder.expunge();

to actually expunge those emails marked as deleted.